# Applying function to a variadic template

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I have a class that holds a map of `Collection<T>`, which is cast into a `void*` for storage purposes.

Each `Collection<T>` can hold an array of IDs, and I want to provide some variadic template magic to be able to tell if some ID exists in some grouping of `Collection<T>`. I'm just not sure how to go about it, after looking over some examples there is something that I am missing.

```
template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    void add_id(int id) {
        ids.emplace_back(id);
    }

    bool has(int id) {
        return std::find(ids.begin(), ids.end(), id) != ids.end();
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> ids {};

};

class Collection {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void insert(T* item) {
        items.insert({std::type_index(typeid(T)), reinterpret_cast<void*>(item)});
    }

    template<typename T>
    bool contains(int id) {
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(items[std::type_index(typeid(T))])->has(id);
    }

    template<typename T>
    bool does_have(int id) {
        return contains<T>(id);
    }
    template<typename First, typename... Rest>
    bool does_have(int id) {
        return contains<First>(id) && does_have<Rest...>(id);
    }

    template<typename First, typename Second, typename... Rest>
    bool does_have(int id) {
        return contains<First>(id) && does_have<Second, Rest...>(id);
    }

private:
    std::map<std::type_index, void*> items;
};
```

[Working Example](https://godbolt.org/z/r8cMYYbzr)

The idea is that, after storing some items in the `Collection` class, I can do something like

`collection.does_have<A<int>, A<bool>, A<double>, A<float>>(15)`

And if the ID 15 exists in all 4, then `does_have` returns true. Otherwise, it's false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have `c++17` (fold expression)

```
template<typename ...Ts>
bool does_have(int id) {
   return (contains<Ts>(id) && ...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get your code to work providing only two overloads of `does_have`:

```
template<typename T>
bool does_have(int id) {
```

and

```
template<typename First, typename... Rest>
bool does_have(int id) {
```

but the latter should be visible only if the size of parameters pack `Rest` is greater than 0. You can do this by SFINAE:

```
template<typename First, typename... Rest, 
    std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Rest) > 0)>* = nullptr>   // <---
bool does_have(int id) {
    return contains<First>(id) && does_have<Rest...>(id);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/onhhGM9vx)

Comment: Just removing the "middle" overload would have been a simpler option IMO.

Comment: @super You are completely right :), thxs for pointing this.

Comment: Do you know of any good books or resources I can use to learn more about sfinae? Fold expression was ultimately what I wanted, but I have a feeling that concepts and fold expressions won't save me from sfinae completely in C++20.

Comment: As online resource [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae),
as a book [Templates - Complete guide](http://www.tmplbook.com/) - 2nd edition.